# JDBC mysql connection much slower on Win8 vs Ubuntu14

Tags: java, mysql, linux, jdbc, windows-8

I need some help with optimization of mysql connection/query. To be honest I am fairly new to DB topic hence I do not know how to start optimization process and how to explain differences in performance between my linux and windows machines.

I have a java application which connects to the DB, retrive some data (about 1 000 000 rows), process them and write out to a set of csv files.
The problem I have is that on my linux machine (i5-2520M and SSD) the whole process takes about 17 seconds while on my windows 8 computer (i7-4790k, SSD disc combined with 7200 rpm HDD) it took almost a minute to execute the same code.

**So it's more than 3 times longer on win than linux.** Can anyone explain why is that the case and how to make the performance comparable on both platforms?

**Update 1:**

JVM is a hotspot I guess version 8.

DB is on localhost.

Cores: 4x4,5 ghz for windows and 2x2,5 ghz for linux both with intel superthreading fancy stuff

There is no any exception caught either on linux or windows even though I have got a try/catch prepared for all of them.

---

Here you have some basic data about the performance and key components of the application. I can provide more details if necessary, just tell me what you need.

```
    public class DBAccesor {
      private Connection mySQLconnection;
      private ResultSet answerDB;
      private Statement query;
      private final String connectionFlags = "&characterEncoding=utf8&useUnicode=true&useSSL=false"
      private String queryBody = "SELECT name, surename FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.person_id = table2.person_id WHERE origin = \"eu\"";
      ...
```

1. Connection established in: *Win* 0.167s vs *Linux* 0.311s

   ```
   Class.forName(driverJDBC);
   DriverManager.setLogWriter(new PrintWriter(System.out));
   mySQLconnection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                DBServer
                + DBName
                + login
                + password
                + connectionFlags);
   ```
2. Query Execution: *Win* 0.023s vs *Linux* 0.01s

   ```
   query = mySQLconnection.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
   query.setFetchSize(Integer.MIN_VALUE);
   answerDB = query.executeQuery(queryBody);
   ```
3. Retrieving data from Result Set: ***Win* 53.020s vs *Linux* 13.282s**

   ```
   ArrayList<Person> results = new ArrayList<Person>();
   while (answerDB.next()) {
     try {
       String name = new String (answerDB.getBytes(1), "UTF-8"); //since 
         //there is a lot of local characters in my data I have to use 
         //getBytes instead of getString. otherwise obtained characters are 
         //corrupted.
       String surname = new String (answerDB.getBytes(2), "UTF-8");
       results.add (new Person(name, surename));
     } catch (SQLException | UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
     }
   }
   ```

The rest of the code is quite strightforward. I have some `paralelStream` processing based on `Arraylist` just created and writing output to files.

4. Data procesing: *Win* 1.109s vs *Linux* 2.976s
5. Writing output to files: *Win* 1.571s vs *Linux* 0.439s

Overall runtime: *Win* 55.880s vs *Linux* 17.083s

Comment: maybe there is a cought exception on the win machine which enters the catch part and prints the stacktrace?

Comment: What about the used JVM? How was your code started, as server or desktop application? Is there a warm up for the JVM, before measuring performance? What about the number of CPU cores? Is the DB remote or on the same machine as the java app?

Comment: thanks for comments. I have updated my question with additional information.
However I am not sure what do you mean by warmup for JVM and code starting as server or desktop app. Could you explain?

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is to retrieve data from a MySQL database and write this data into your disk. Now the thing is that it's not about which OS you are using. Seeing the configurations of your two machines, I see that you are using a SSD on the Linux one and a HDD on the windows one. You should know that the Read / Write capabilities of a SSD disk are much more better and faster than with a HDD, so I think that it is from there that the differences of performance come from.

I refer you to read this thread of discussion for further information:
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/59828/ssd-vs-hdd-for-databases

Comment: Hm, the last part of my program- this one which is writing processed data from memory to files on disc is dealing with more data much faster. do you know any way to check if your guess is right? any cool disc write/read analysis or other stuff?
anyway thanks for the link.

Comment: what's more i have just checked localization of my db and it is stored on the SSD, only output files are located on HDD. so my weak performance is not due to difference in disc technology.

Comment: In this case the performance comes from the access possibility of the SSD which is higher than the HDD one... Sometimes 15x faster :)

Comment: Make sure the HDD is not used for anything on the Windows machine during the test. Maybe writing the output to HDD is slowing down the application? Or perhaps the swap file is stored there?